# Smoothing borders of polygons taking a layer of points into account

Tags: qgis, clustering, smoothing

[image]I'm trying to smooth borders that separate clusters of points.
GRASS instrument v.generalize.smooth works pretty well, except that in some cases the points end up on the wrong side of the smoothed border. On the picture: green line is the correct "unsmoothed" border, purple line -- is the "smoothed" border; the bottom point should belong to a different cluster than the upper three points, yet, due to smoothing it is now in the same cluster.

My question: is there an instrument in QGIS (or anywhere else) that allows to smooth borders of polygons taking a layer of points into account?